# Missing Microsoft.SQLServer dlls

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Ok, I installed the Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components here file:///C:/Users/davids/AppData/Local/Temp/instructions_enu.htm but I guess these dlls are not in this.

Anyone know where the heck I can get these?  Yes, I'm running SQL 2008 so they are missing because they're for 2005.

Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
...

Comment: Aren't they installed in the GAC?

Comment: not sure...why would I have to do this manually?

Comment: I remember having to carry those in my local folder next to my executable because the gac had them compiled platform specific(gac had win32 and my app was running in x64) or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

You can find these DLLs registered at the `GAC` (`C:\Windows\assembly`). If you find them there you can export, check this link on how to export DLL from Assembly folder:
http://waelouf.blogspot.com/2009/08/adding-microsoft-report-viewer-in.html